# C# xmlをインスタンスして別Formで挿入または並び替え後の継承をしたいです

Tags: c#, xml

```
<AppSettings>
  <FileFolder>D:\C#作成物</FileFolder>
  <SKey>User0002</SKey>
  <Users>
    <User Id="User0004">
      <date>2019/10/16</date>
      <Key />
      <Address>D:\C#作成物\顔マーク_フリー素材\img048_22.png</Address>
    </User>
    <User Id="User0002">
      <date>2019/10/16</date>
      <Key />
      <Address>D:\C#作成物\顔マーク_フリー素材\img038_39.png</Address>
    </User>
    <User Id="User0003">
      <date>2019/10/16</date>
      <Key>３</Key>
      <Address />
    </User>
  </Users>
</AppSettings>
```

---

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string FileFolder { get; set; };
    public string SKey { get; set; };
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public class User
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    [NonSerialized()]
    private static AppSettings _instance;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public static AppSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new AppSettings();
            return _instance;
        }
        set { _instance = value; }
    }
}
```

---

※xml追加などの作業はすべてMainFormで行い、ロード・セーブはインスタンスを行ったAppSettings.csでします

案1（MainForm）addで最後に追加後、ソートする

```
            var query = (from x in AppSettings.Instance.Users
                         orderby x.Id
                         select x);
```

問題点：このソートではインスタンスに継承されないので、インスタンスにソートを反映させる方法を知りたいです。

案2（MainForm）インスタンスのId検索後、その手前にId以下date、Key、Addressを挿入したいです

indexを指定して挿入すれば良さそうですが、指定Idのindexを取得するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

申し訳ありませんが、お力をお借りしたくよろしくお願いいたします

追記：
挿入方法など難しかったので、Idの情報や子ノードを消さずに変更する事で対応することにしました。よって質問自体は不要になってしまったのですが、今後必要になった場合に挿入の方法、ソートの反映に関してアドバイスいただけたら嬉しく思います。
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

この定義注意してください。

```
public List Users { get; set; }
public class User
```

List Users ですが、Classのリストの定義ではなくて、下記のようにしてくだい。
`public List<User> Users{get;set;}`

なお、public class User　の宣言はpublic class AppSettingsの外に定義してください。

```
public class AppSettings
{
public string FileFolder { get; set; };
public string SKey { get; set; };
public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
public string date { get; set; }
public string Key { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

上記のように直して試しましょう。もしまた問題があれば再連絡してください。

Comment: 上記提案の通りpublic class Userを別クラスで外に出してみました。問題なく動いてます。すみません。無知でなぜ外に出すのかが良く分かってないです。修正前のは問題ある記述だったでしょうか？

Comment: 内部クラスの説明は下記のURLを参照してください。https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1805/09/news016.html

Comment: 修正前のList　Users　これは問題です。使用上はクラスUserのリストを定義して利用したいですが、宣言する時、Usersの型を指定していなかったため。

Comment: 確かにUserに対して関連付けがちゃんとしてませんでした。よくデバックで注意されず動いてくれたものだと感心してしまいました。指摘ありがとうございました。参照先にソートについて書かれてて読み進めてます。ただなかなか理解するところまで行かず……

Comment: 簡単に説明なら、何故か内部クラス利用するか。そのクラスの情報を外部で直接アクセスしないようにするため。なので、内部クラスなら、publicではなくて、privateがよく使います。なお、実際のプロジェクト中で、内部クラスの使用は少ないですので、短時間に理解しなくても焦る必要はない。Good Luck!